# Golang gRPC default values

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

Given the following protobuf definition:

```
message MyMessage {
    string Foo = 1;
    int From = 2;
    int To = 3;
}
```

Then I have a case where I want to send in just the Foo string from the client, no problem.
The issue arises in the server, where I want to know if From and To has a value (UNIX timestamps).
If the value is not explicitly set by the client, then Go will set the value to 0, which is a fully valid Unix timestamp. At this point, I have no idea whether the Client intended to give me 1970-01-01 00:00:00 or if it meant to leave it empty.

I could add two bools which say whether or not From and To has been set by the client, but I feel like there should be a more elegant solution than this.

Is there a way to actually find out if the client intended to send null-values, or if it actually set the value to `0`? Same goes for `""` for strings and so forth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot distinguish between absent fields and fields set to their default value in proto3. This is by design. Quoting xfxyjwf in [Issue 1606](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/1606#issuecomment-281832148):

> - Rationale of removing field presence in proto3:
>
>   - Field presence in proto2 has caused confusions and it complicates the semantics, e.g. one
>       has to distinguish between absence fields vs fields set to their default values; users usually
>       check presence before accessing the fields which is unnecessary. We believe in most cases,
>       field presence info is not needed.
>   - Removing field presence makes Proto3 significantly easier to implement with open struct
>       representations, as in languages like Android Java (go/nano-proto), or Go. The easier
>       implementation in turn makes it better accessible to external implementer communities.
> - If such presence info is explicitly needed, there are several workarounds, e.g. wrappers, explicit
>     has_field boolean. Oneof can also be used if backward wire compatibility with proto2 optional
>     field is desired.